# Split string and change value in JS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help to solve this one problem which seems to be more complicated than I expected...

I have an array that looks like this:
`[[G113428, 03-35, ], [G114696, 04-17, ], [, , ], [G298962, 05-19, ], [G117633, , ], [G117648, , ], [G119907, 04-40, 03-49], [G119912, 04-38, 03-47], [G119927, 04-41, 03-50], [, , ], [G246909, 05-23, ], [G250157, 04-51, ], [G250249, 05-3, ], [G298982, 04-66, ], [G293310, 04-7, ], [G298997, , ], [G297871, 05-9, ], [G297886, 05-39, ], [G297891, 04-60, ], [G297918, 04-61, ], [G297923, 05-1, ], [G297938, 05-2, ], [G297943, 04-48, ], [G297963, 04-52, ], [G297978, 03-59, ], [G297983, 03-60, ], [G201069, 04-6, ], [G201094, 04-5, 04-5], [G201126, 04-4, ], [G201203, 05-5, ], [G299008, 04-24, ], [G206967, 04-22, ]]`

Each array has 3 elements, in some cases, there are null elements as well.
I need to change the second and the third element of every array.

For example, as you can see in the above array
at the second position of few arrays, we have this: `04-17, 04-66, 04-61, 04-6...`
All I want to do is change those values according to the second value.
So it should be like this:

`04-6` ➔ `04-1`

`04-17` ➔ `04-2`

`04-61` ➔ `04-3`

`04-66` ➔ `04-4`

Have no idea how it can be solved.... I've tried to split first the second and third element but it didn't go well...
Here is my code so far but I don`t think it will be of any use for you, because it returns the original array.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,11,sheet.getLastRow(),3);
  var values = range.getValues();

  //Logger.log(values)

  function splitV(arr){
    var nowa = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     arr[i][1].split("-")
    }
    return arr;
  }

const splited = splitV(values)
 Logger.log(splited)

}
```

If there is anyone who could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: First `04-X` -> `04-1`, second `04-X` -> `04-2`, ... First `05-X` -> `05-1`, second `05-X` -> `05-2`, ... ? Or is there more logic involved?

Comment: @Andreas nope, there is no more logic involved in it. Just need to sort the first values and then put new numbers

Comment: what is with the third element of the inner arrays?

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry for that! third element looks the same as second

Comment: _"I don't think it will be any useful for you"_ - Yes, because the function doesn't work because of a `ReferenceError`.  Please make this a [mcve] with actual data to work with. It should not be our job to first generate test input data.

Comment: What should be done with the rows with a null value on the second column? This feels like a single step in a function. What is your end goal?

Comment: @Martí they should stay null as they are. My goal is to fix the order of all things in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idk if this is what you need but i've come up with that solution:

```js
arr = [["a", "04-12", "04-4"], ["b", "04-3", "02-5"], ["c", null, "02-3"], ["d", null, null]]

max = {}
const newArr = arr.map(group => group.map((v, i) => {
    if(i > 0) {
        let val = v ? v.split("-")[0] + "-" : ""
        let index = max[val] ?? 1
        max[val] = index + 1
        return val + index
    }
    return v
}))

console.log(newArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have no idea but I am getting the syntax error at `const newArr = arr.map(group => group.map((v, i) => {`

Comment: If I run the snippet everything works fine, is your array called `arr`?

Comment: on the snippet works well... Is it because of google sheets? yes, my array is called `arr`

Comment: it started to work when I changed `??` operator to `||`. I am not sure but it seems like google spreadsheet does not recognize this nullish coalescing operator (??)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for getting a incrementing number of the same group.

```js
var data = [['G113428', '03-35',], ['G114696', '04-17',], [, ,], ['G298962', '05-19',], ['G117633', ,], ['G117648', ,], ['G119907', '04-40', '03-49'], ['G119912', '04-38', '03-47'], ['G119927', '04-41', '03-50'], [, ,], ['G246909', '05-23',], ['G250157', '04-51',], ['G250249', '05-3',], ['G298982', '04-66',], ['G293310', '04-7',], ['G298997', ,], ['G297871', '05-9',], ['G297886', '05-39',], ['G297891', '04-60',], ['G297918', '04-61',], ['G297923', '05-1',], ['G297938', '05-2',], ['G297943', '04-48',], ['G297963', '04-52',], ['G297978', '03-59',], ['G297983', '03-60',], ['G201069', '04-6',], ['G201094', '04-5', '04-5'], ['G201126', '04-4',], ['G201203', '05-5',], ['G299008', '04-24',], ['G206967', '04-22',]],
    process = function (h) {
        return function(s) {
            if (s === undefined) return s;
            s = s.split('-', 1)[0];
            return [s, h[s] = (h[s] || 0) + 1].join('-');
        };
    }({});
    result = data.map(function(a) { return [a[0], process(a[1]), process(a[2])]; });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have no idea but I am gettint syntax error again at this line `process = (h => s => {`

Answer (score 0):

Since you also want the data sorted, you could do the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const values = [/* values */]


  // Sort by the secod element with nulls and empty cells at the end
  values.sort((rowA, rowB) => {
    const a = rowA[1]
    const b = rowB[1]

    if (a === b) return 0
    if (a === null || a === '') return 1
    if (b === null || b === '') return -1

    return a.localeCompare(b)
  })


  // Reset the counting as specified
  let currentGroup, i
  for (let row of values) {
    if (row[1]) {
      const group = row[1].split('-', 2)[0]
      
      if (group !== currentGroup) {
        currentGroup = group
        i = 1
      }
      row[1] = `${currentGroup}-${i}`
      i++
    }
  }

  // Use "values"
}
```

At the end of this sample code `values` is sorted and the second element has changed its value as specified.

Answer (score -4):

```
arrayOfArrays.forEach((array) => {
    // do whatever you want with the second item
    // array[1] = 'whatever';
});
```